# Why can't I change index values?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to change the value of an index but I keep getting the same error and I have no clue how to fix it. Its for a school project so if anyone could help me out that would be much appreciated.

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   list/scorebord/writing.py", line 18, in 
>       if naam == spelerlijst["spelers"]: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import json
spelerlijst = []
with open("test1.json") as spelerlijst:
    spelerlijst = json.load(spelerlijst)

speler = input("geef een naam")
spelers = {"speler": speler, "score": 0}
spelerlijst.append(spelers)
print (spelerlijst)
with open ("test1.json", "w") as data:
    json.dump (spelerlijst, data)
print ("Speler {} is aangemaakt.".format(speler))

for spelers in spelerlijst:
    naam = input("welke speler krijgt een punt")
    if naam == spelerlijst["spelers"]:
        spelers["score"] += int(score)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant index an list by a string. If you want to do that, you must do it like this: `val = spelerlijst[spelerlijst.index("spelers")]`

Comment: That error is pretty clear about the problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are having is that the thing you are trying to index is a list, not a dict. a list can only be indexed with numbers, starting from 0. if you want to have indexes as strings, use a dict, or as mentioned above, use the `index` method of the list type (similar to the `find` method of strings) to extract the index from the list.